# Ошибка в while (принимать только номера от 0 до 200)

Tags: c

```
 printf("Introduza a sua altura (m): ");
  scanf("%f", &altura);

 while(altura < 0.59 || altura > 2.46)
 {
 printf("A altura introduzida e invalida, introduza de novo!\n");
 printf("Introduza a sua altura (m): ");
  scanf("%f", &altura);
 }
```

Есть этот while, но при вводе любой буквы - выбивает ошибку (постоянно копирует одно и то же сообщение)
Как лимит сделать, что бы принимало только числа и только от 0 до 3?

Answer (score 2):

scanf/sscanf прочитает float из строки вида "0blablabla". Поэтому необходим другой вариант.
Валентин09, разбирайся.

```
const size_t BUFSZ = 256;
char buf[BUFSZ];
char *pEnd;
float altura;

do
{
    printf("Introduza a sua altura (m): ");
    // gets_s вернет NULL, если строка содержит больше, чем BUFSZ-1 символов
    if (gets_s(buf, BUFSZ) != NULL)
    {
        // конвертим прочитанную строку во float
        altura = strtof(buf, &pEnd);
        // strtof поместит в pEnd адрес символа, следующего сразу после строкового представления числа.
        // если ничего не преобразовано, то pEnd будет указывать на начало буфера.
        if (pEnd > buf && 0.0 <= altura && altura <= 200)
            break; // введено валидное значение, выход из цикла
    }
    printf("A altura introduzida e invalida, introduza de novo!\n");
}
while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Читайте строку (а не число) и пытайтесь выяснить, число в ней или нет, при помощи `sscanf`.

Проблема с вашим кодом такая: если вы вводите не число, то `scanf` просто останавливается, не удалив буквы из входного потока (и не пометив их прочитанными), и возвращает 0. Поэтому следующий вызов `scanf` в цикле не ждёт ввода (потому что в потоке есть непрочитанные символы), опять пытается прочитать число, опять натыкается на буквы, процесс повторяется -- замкнутый круг.

Если же вы сначала читаете строку, то что бы пользователь не ввёл, оно прочтётся. Потом вы выясняете, было ли это число, и в зависимости от этого крутите цикл дальше или нет.

Вот немного информации о том, какие ещё проблемы у scanf: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html.

Comment: А как именно то?, в этом чАвО не ясно написанно что и как.. =(

Comment: Валентин09: дописал ответ

Comment: @Валентин09: а где проблема? Как прочитать строку? Смотрите в сторону параметра `%s` в `scanf`. Как прочитать из строки число? Смотрите `sscanf`.

Comment: и как сделать это? вобще мясо, начинаю только...

Comment: @Валентин09: ну не делать же мне за вас д/з. Почитайте, как работает `scanf`/`sscanf`, разберитесь, тогда то, что я написал, станет понятным. Если вы получите готовое решение, не разберётесь никогда.

Comment: понял, буду пробывать.

Comment: @Валентин09: удачи! со временем всё будет казаться проще.